# What tool can assist with creating a Myst-like game?

Tags: game-development

There are some tools designed to help users easily make specific types of adventure games. E.g. TADS 3 has a developer tool for making text adventures, AGI Studio helps with making '80s Sierra-style adventure games, and SCI Companion helps with making '90s style adventure games. Is there any tool to assist with creating a Myst-like game?

Note:

- The tool does not need to help with creating the 3D renders, these should be done in a 3D modelling tool.
- The tool should focus on helping developers go from having pre-rendered images to being able to link them so players can click to walk around, or interact with the environment.

Is there any tool specifically designed to help create first-person point-of-view mouse-navigated Myst-like games, using pre-rendered graphics?

Comment: I guess such tool should appear as an engine - maybe ask in [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)?